# How could i get number type value from javascript .toFixed(2) method

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get number from javascript .toFixed(2) method, using this

```
var number = 123;
var floatType = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
alert(floatType) ===> result "123.00"
```

I want to get result in Number type i.e (123.00)
How could i get it easily??

Thanks

Comment: You already have that value in the `number` variable. If you want to force the display of decimal places then you have to convert the variable to a string - which is what `toFixed()` does.

Comment: the problem is the number type value of `123.00` is `123` so your purpose is not served

Comment: I think you are having a misconception about how number values are stored. How a number is *displayed* and how its value is represented internally are two independent things. Also, `parseFloat` expects a **string** as argument. Passing a number does basically nothing. If you explain which problem you are trying to solve through that, we could help you better.

Comment: I am trying to use google api for charts, its working fine, but values(currency, amount)  are not displaying as decimal. e.g its $100, i want $100 to be displayed as $100.00.
Thanks